# laravel symlink is changed when code is pushed to live site

Tags: laravel-5, storage, symlink, gitignore

I am using laravel 5.5's storage symlink to store images. When I push code to the git and pull from live site then symlink path on live site becomes same as is on my local code . 
My local has this symlink

```
 storage -> /home/path/to/project/app/public/
```

But live site expects this symlink path

```
 storage -> /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/project_code/storage/app/public/
```

Every time I have to delete symlink and create it again on live site.
I have do these steps on live site

```
cd public
rm storage
cd ..
php artisan storage:link
```

after doing these steps my symlink becomes according to live site and then it starts working.
Live site should have this symlink

```
storage -> /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/project_code/storage/app/public/
```

project_code/.gitignore :

```
public/storage
```

project_code/storage/app/.gitignore

```
 *
 !public/
 !.gitignore
```

How I can get rid of this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your symlink points to another location within the same project, you can safely use relative paths while linking, instead of having absolute one (which is what `artisan` is setting up). That would require manual linking though:

```
cd app/public
ln -s ../storage/app/public storage
```

Remove current `storage` symlink first if you have it already.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider setting up a [post-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks) in the target Git repo (the one you are pushing to). See [this one](https://gist.github.com/vool/2e76b5062b71c8aab354) for instance.

In that hook, you can add any step you need (like fixing the symlink).

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful to run some commands automatically.