# php artisan storage:link linking wrong directory

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need advice to setup `php artisan storage:link` in my .ebextensions/setup.config. Currently, after the command being executed my storage folder are linked under path "/var/app/ondeck/storage/app/public" instead of "/var/www/html/storage/app/public". Below are my setup configuration.

```
06-link_storage:
    command: "php artisan storage:link"
    cwd: "/var/app/ondeck"
```

Here's a screenshot of the path linked in one of my instances.

[image]

I've also tried changing the path to /var/www/html. However the path link also invalid.

```
06-link_storage:
    command: "php artisan storage:link"
    cwd: "/var/www/html"
```

[image]

Any help or advice would mean a lot to me. Thanks.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919060/laravel-symlink-is-changed-when-code-is-pushed-to-live-site

Comment: Thank you very much Afraz! The solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

The only option that worked for me was creating the symlink manually using a [postdeploy hook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html):

```
<project root>/
├── .platform/
│   └── hooks/
│       └── postdeploy/
│           └── 01_symlink.sh
```

---

`01_symlink.sh` having the `DocumentRoot` at `/public`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
ln -sf ../storage/app/public storage
```